# Does the order of transactions matter when increasing compute units?

Tags: transactions

When sending a transaction, it is possible to increase the amount of compute units that can be used. From the Solana Cookbook:

```
const modifyComputeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ 
  units: 1000000 
});

const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ 
  microLamports: 1 
});

const transaction = new Transaction()
.add(modifyComputeUnits)
.add(addPriorityFee)
.add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      toPubkey: toAccount,
      lamports: 10000000,
    })
  );
```

I used this functionality for a function call in my program where I needed significantly more compute units than the default amount. However in my case, the first transaction was the function call and `modifyComputeUnits` and `addPriorityFee` came after it:

```
const transaction = functionCallTx
.add(modifyComputeUnits)
.add(addPriorityFee)
```

I read here on Solana StackExchange that the order of these transactions matters, however I was able to get the function to execute after ordering transactions as shown above. Is this a coincidence? Does it actually matter which one of these transaction comes first?

Comment: I had a similar observation and I think that currently it's not needed to place the instruction of `ComuteBudgetProgram` at the start of the transaction.
From the code it seems there was that need prior v1.11.0 (probably https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/commit/cde15ff687b27c0d9df29304f8b94c326b67f021#diff-4ccc0bd50c1235d66c74b57d44afc61b9855a1e3ec2e7c27ec215c4f6a716d25L143) but now the code seems to look through all instructions in transaction and consider the compute budget being at any place: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/v1.14.13/program-runtime/src/compute_budget.rs#L137

Comment: @chalda You're right, I tested this again with a different function that exceeds the 200K limit and it seems like the order doesn't matter at all.